Unable to Assign IP Address to FastEthernet Interface on Cisco Router
I am currently working on some Cisco Packet Tracers project and I have run into some problems when trying to configure an Ip address to a FastEthernet Port.
For more context I am using a 2901 Router to which I added a HWIC-4ESW Module in order to have extra FastEthernet ports. This is the basic domain.

So the problem comes when I tried to configure it as Any normal GEthernet port that already comes with the Router.

Now I understand It probably has to do with the fact Its a port added by a module. But then the question comes. How can I fix it? I am honestly new to both networking and Cisco Packet Tracer so I literally have no clue.
I have tried configuring the no switchport command but it gives an incomplete error message. Any feedback or advice is really appreciated! As well as any resources to learn more about networking! Thank you for your time.

That is not a router interface, it is a switch module interface, and you cannot use it as a router interface. You need to choose a router with more router interfaces or use a router module for your router.
The interfaces on a switch module for the routers cannot be used as router interfaces. They also have limitations as switch interfaces.
Also, Packet Tracer is a tool to help you pass the CCNA. It has limitations compared to real-world hardware and software, but even with real hardware routers, you have the limitations of switch modules used in routers.
